# C: Help with Custom strpos() Function

Tags: c, string, strpos

I have the following function:

```
int strpos(const char *needle, const char *haystack)
{
    int neLen, haLen, foundPos, nePos, i;
    char temp;

    neLen = strlen(needle);
    haLen = strlen(haystack);

    if(haLen < neLen)
        return -1;

    nePos    = 0;
    foundPos = -1;
    i        = 0;

    while((temp = *haystack++) != '\0'
          && (i < (haLen-neLen+1) || foundPos > -1)
          && nePos < neLen)
    {
        if(temp == *needle+nePos)
        {
            if(nePos == 0)
                foundPos = i;
            nePos++;
        }
        else
        {
            nePos = 0;
            foundPos = -1;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return foundPos;
}
```

It works properly when I search for a single character:

```
printf("Strpos: %d\n", strpos("a", "laoo")); // Result: "Strpos: 1"
```

But it improperly with longer string:

```
printf("Strpos: %d\n", strpos("ao", "laoo")); // Result: "Strpos: -1"
```

**What is the problem?**

**Bonus question:** is the `while` loop properly broken into multiple lines? What is the accepted way to do this?

EDIT: `strlen()` is, naturally, a custom function that returns the length of the string. This works properly.

Comment: Is this homework, or do we really get bonus rep for answering the bonus question?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. When faced with code like this that doesn't work it's usually quicker to rewrite it from scratch than try and debug it. Why are you rewriting a standard library function anyway? I suggest, if you really want to debug this code, that you add printf values to key points to determine what is happening in what order.

Comment: @Myforkwik I'd appreciate it if you would tell me *why* the code is awful instead of just saying it. @MAK it isn't homework, it was just my idea of a way to say that I would appreciate it if people would answer that sub-question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is of the standard bang-your-head-against-the-wall-in-an-infinite-loop-and-wonder-why-the-hell-you're-a-programmer variety.

```
if(temp == *needle+nePos)
```

Should be:

```
if(temp == *(needle+nePos))
```

Comment: The problem pointed out by @JeremyP is real, though - try `strpos("ao", "aaoo")` to see it in action.

Answer (score 3):

Each time you go round the loop you get the next character from haystack.  So if needle has two characters by the time you have finished comparing needle with the substring of haystack beginning at position 0, the haystack pointer is pointing at position 2 (for a two character needle).

This means that you skip comparing needle with the substring of haystack beginning at position 1.